# corresponding indices from two different matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

In an algorithm, in each level, I have two corresponding matrices in a way one of them has 4 times more element than the other. like children and parent, but i need to have the corresponding elements. consider the two following indices as an example for a level

```
1 5 9  13
2 6 10 14   and  1 3
3 7 11 15        2 4
4 8 12 16
```

so for example, I want to receive the element by the index of 1 from the second matrix when i have each of 1,2,5,6 element indices from the first matrix or 2 when i have 3,4,7,8 or 3 for 9,10,16,14 and so on. how can i do that?

as an another example for another level:

```
1 9  17 25 33 41 49 57
2 10 18 26 34 42 50 58
3 11 19 27 35 43 51 59  and  1 5 9  13
4 12 20 28 36 44 52 60       2 6 10 14
5 13 21 29 37 45 53 61       3 7 11 15
6 14 22 30 38 46 54 62       4 8 12 16
7 15 23 31 39 47 55 63
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I want to receive element 1 element index". Can you explain more clearly "for these two matrices A and B, when the input is X I want the output to be Y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing that:

```
% Size of matrix A (8x8)
sizeA = 8;

% Size of matrix B (4x4)
sizeB = 4;

% Index of element on matrix A
idxA = 43;

% That is how you can get the corresponding index on matrix B
[r, c] = ind2sub([sizeA sizeA], idxA);
idxB = sub2ind([sizeB sizeB], ceil(r / 2), ceil(c / 2))
```

It will give you `idxB = 10`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that `reshape` could be helpful for you.

Consider

```
A = [1 5 9  13;
     2 6 10 14;
     3 7 11 15;
     4 8 12 16];
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A, [2 2 2 2]), [2 4 1 3]), [4 4]);
B
  1  2  5  6
  3  4  7  8
  9 10 13 14
 11 12 15 16
```

Now you have a nice mapping of the indices from one level to the next.

`B(1,:)` corresponds to all the indices that map to element 1 in your second array, etc.

When the matrix gets larger (2n x 2n), the operation becomes

```
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A, [2 n 2 n]), [2 4 1 3]), [n*n 4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the 2D indices for the first matrix, then you just divide each by 2 to get the second pair indices:

```
r = 3;
c = 2;
% Then A(r,c) corresponds to B(floor(r/2), floor(c/2))
```

If you DON'T know the indices, but instead have the element value itself, you have to find the 2D index first:

```
val = 7;  % test value
[r c] = find(A==val);
other_val = B(floor(r/2), floor(c/2));
```

Comment: Peter : I want to use the column wise indexing, Suppose that the matrix with more element is divided into 4 parts, so for example the elements by the index 1,2,5,6 are together, because of that i am using a loop and i have the 1, 2, 5 or 6 i want to have the element with index 1 from the second matrix